# Make a base server jar using Swagger codegen playframework

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, swagger-codegen

First at all, I want to clarify that I use `swagger-codegen` to autogenerate code for a `Play Framework` based service.

I currently using the same swagger API description replicated in several projects that implements the same API but have different internal implementation.

I think that it would be better to create an independent JAR that contains all autogenerated code (***models*** and ***controllers***) according to the API defined in the `swagger.json` file and then add it to each project for both to reduce duplication and to improve mantainance and save compilation time.

My doubd is if it is posible to bind routes to the independent JAR controllers or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can simply add a dependency to your jar file. The jar file must contain a routes file with a unique name (e.g. api.routes) . In every project you can include the routes file like this:

conf/routes

```
->  /api    api.Routes
```

Comment: The included routes file (e.g. api.routes) could contain all routes for the autogenerated code